# Python: Iterate through directory and subdirectory

Tags: python

I want to delete the whole content of 3.000 files using python and keep only some specific lines.

File.txt

```
    Motion
    FileName "d:/monster"
    Dur 0.6321
    Acc 0.1121
    SOME LINE
    ASD
    SDAF
    DS
    V
    SADF
    SDV
    SDAFAV
```

This code Works perfect for a single file

```
with open(x, "r+") as f:
    new_f = f.readlines()
    f.seek(0)

    for line in new_f:
        if re.match(r"^(Dur|Acc)", line):
            f.write(line)

    f.truncate()
```

I tried this way, to iterate through all files with extension .txt

```
files = glob.glob('dirtest')
for x in files:

    with open(x, "r+") as f:
        new_f = f.readlines()
        f.seek(0)

        for line in new_f:
            if re.match(r"^(Dur|Acc)", line):
                f.write(line)

        f.truncate()
```

But nothing happens.
How should the final script look? To iterate through all 3.000 files

Comment: Where are you matching files with `.txt` extension?

Comment: Try `glob.glob("dirtest/*.txt")`

Comment: But that won't recurse into subdirectories. Take a look at `os.walk()`.

Comment: Seems like this would be easier with `sed`.

Comment: `sed -n -i '/^\(Dur\|Acc\)/p' dirtest/*.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use listdir

```
import os
for file in os.listdir("filesPath"):
     if file.endswith(".txt"):
         with open(x, "r+") as f:
             new_f = f.readlines()
             f.seek(0)
             for line in new_f:
                 if re.match(r"^(Dur|Acc)", line):
                 f.write(line)

             f.truncate()
```

Hope it helps